# Sync the two mpandroidcharts graphs dragging and zomming

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and I have a requirement that i have to sync the dragging and zooming of two graphs, like if i zoom out, zoom in or drag one any of one graph then other graph should be zoomed out, zoomed in or dragged to same extent on X-axis. 
Example: If i drag the upper graph to 12th point on X-axis then lower graph should also be dragged to 12th point on X-axis automatically.

[image: MyGraphs]

Guys i need need some idea how to do this, i am enough familiar with mpchartandroid library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a function to do this, i am calling this function of Drag and scale listener. Working perfectly.

```
private void syncCharts(Chart mainChart, LineChart[] otherCharts) {
        Matrix mainMatrix;
        float[] mainVals = new float[9];
        Matrix otherMatrix;
        float[] otherVals = new float[9];
        mainMatrix = mainChart.getViewPortHandler().getMatrixTouch();
        mainMatrix.getValues(mainVals);


        for (LineChart tempChart : otherCharts) {

            otherMatrix = tempChart.getViewPortHandler().getMatrixTouch();
            otherMatrix.getValues(otherVals);
            otherVals[Matrix.MSCALE_X] = mainVals[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
            otherVals[Matrix.MTRANS_X] = mainVals[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            otherVals[Matrix.MSKEW_X] = mainVals[Matrix.MSKEW_X];
            otherMatrix.setValues(otherVals);
            tempChart.getViewPortHandler().refresh(otherMatrix, tempChart, true);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `OnChartGestureListener`.

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart